# Translation of date in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, internationalization

There is a function on the site that displays the date, but the date is displayed in English, how to correctly build date_i18n (). in the code so that the date is displayed on the same language as the site

this is the date output code

```
function dt_post_date($format = false, $echo = true) {
if( ! is_string( $format ) || empty($format) ) {
    $format = 'j F, Y';
}
$date = sprintf( __d('%1$s') , get_the_time($format) );
if( $echo ){
    echo $date;
} else {
    return $date;
}
}
```

how to embed date_i18n () into this code

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you check the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/date_i18n) for the `date_i18n()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified function and hope this will solve the issue.

```
function dt_post_date($format = false, $echo = true) {
    if( ! is_string( $format ) || empty($format) ) {
        $format = 'j F, Y';
    }
    $date = date_i18n($format, get_the_time('U', true));
    if( $echo ){
        echo $date;
    } else {
        return $date;
    }
}
```

If you want to display the 'Post' time instead of current time, replace `get_the_time()` with `get_post_time()`.